# Intent for image upload

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I would like to create an intent, where when user send an image, it will trigger this intent. How could this be done in dialogflow?

Note: It need to support cross platform (eg: facebook messenger, telegram)

Answer (score 0):

I believe DialogFlow only supports text or speech as an input. What you can do is suggest images in the form of a carousel and allow the user select one. This will only work for Google Assistant however. If you're interested and need help, check out this codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-3/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0